# Does it make sense for a mod to edit a question and also vote to close?

Tags: discussion

I don't want to single anyone out, but I've seen this a couple of times: A moderator or someone with vote-to-close capabilities edits a question for clarity, spelling, or grammar, and also votes to close it. Does that even make sense?

The one exception I would see is if someone posted a "rant question" and you tried to edit out the rant to get the good question to the surface, and then the OP keeps reverting it back. In such "lost causes" it would make sense to have both edited and voted to close.

Comment: There's a key difference here between a moderator, and a 3K+ rep user: the former can instantly close/lock/delete a poor question, while the latter must assume that, should others not agree, his close vote will be wasted and the question will live on - in this case, trying to improve the question is more productive.

Comment: @Mr. CRT - absolutely, I've done this before. You don't assume your voice is the voice of the community. I've even answered questions I've voted to close for the same reason - I think the question is inappropriate but if the community disagrees then I feel there is something worth saying.

Answer (score 13):

It can make sense; there's no reason for incorrect spelling or grammar to hang around as a broken window, even on a question you think should be closed.